50-Fache: Wieso gibt es ein „e" am Ende von „Fache"?
In einem Kursbuch habe ich gerade Folgendes gelesen:

...das 50-Fache des eigenen Körpergewichts...

Die Bedeutung ist mir klar. Aber die Form von „50-Fache" kommt mir unbekannt vor.  Wieso ist „Fach" großgeschrieben? Weil „50-Fache" ein Nomen ist?  Und warum endet es mit „e"?  Ich kann bisher keine Antwort finden.

Das Suffix -fach bildet Adjektive.

ein mehrfacher Olympiasieger
der zweifache Olympiasieger

Diese können wie jedes Adjektiv als Nomen gebraucht werden.

ein Vielfaches des Kaufpreises
das Dreifache des Kaufpreises

Als Nomen werden sie nach § 57 des amtlichen Regelwerks großgeschrieben.
Wenn man das Dreifache mit einer Ziffer schreiben möchte, wird daraus das 3-Fache; siehe § 40 Abs. 3 und im Wörterverzeichnis unter acht.

Du schreibst "~fache(s)" aber nicht groß.

Wolltest du sagen, daß die Großschreibung nicht den amtlichen Regeln entspricht? Tut sie schon.

Ich glaube dass beim "50-Fachen" in der Fragestellung der ursprüngliche Autor die Regel falsch angewendet hat. Es muss ja "das Fünfzigfache" heißen, genau so wie "das Dreifache". Will man fünfzig als Zahl schreiben, sollte daraus "das 50-fache" werden, oder?

@Raketenolli Nicht laut den amtlichen Regeln.

Stimmt, ist ja eine Nominalisierung analog zum "17-Jährigen". Danke für die Ergänzung zu Deiner Antwort.

@DavidVogt: Ich dachte, sowohl der Bindestrich, als auch der Großbuchstabe in der Wortmitte seien falsch, aber der Duden empfiehlt tatsächlich https://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/sprachratgeber/Bildungen-mit-fach bei der Verwendung des Bindestrichs einen Großbuchstaben und schreckt auch nicht vor 3-Zimmer-Wohnung zurück. "Das 50fache ...", "der 12tonner", "eine 17jährige" finde ich einzig logisch.

Die Endung -e ist fast der Regelfall:

Das Gute, Schöne, Wahre, Ungesagte, Unbezahlbare

Wikipedia schreibt dazu:

Die Beugung erfolgt meist nach demselben Muster wie die Beugung normaler attributiver Adjektive (die neue Kollegin → die Neue). Es gibt aber systematische und auch lexikalisierte Ausnahmen

Die Großschreibung des -Fachen finde ich trotz Richtigkeit (siehe Antwort von @DavidVogt) als schlechtere Lösung gegenüber dem ebenfalls erlaubten 50fachen, auch wenn Letzterem nicht mehr anzusehen ist, dass es ein Substantiv ist.
